# Mobile Redirect Script not redirecting Safari

Tags: redirect, mobile, safari

This is the mobile redirect script I use. For some reason it does not redirect Safari for the iPhone. I added in |safari| just as you see |blackberry| but it redirects Google Chrome, even on a computer. Does anyone have any advice to get Safari to work on this code or a seperate code that works independantly on Safari that I could add in?

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[  
        var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
if (mobile) {document.location = "http://www.grossmag.com/mobi";}  
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect worked. It was the site I was working on that was causing the issue. It was built in Joomla 2.5 and had a built in redirect for iPhones and was never getting to my redirect. I uninstalled the Joomla mobile plugin and it allowed users to be redirected to the mobile site I had built.